# Cannot convert `object' expression to type `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject'

Tags: c#, mono, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

I started a new MonoTouch project.  I opened the Interface Builder and created a button and outlet.  I hooked up the button to the outlet.  I saved the XIB then went back to MonoDevelop and attempted to build the project.  I am getting errors in the generated XIB Designer file.  The errors are:

```
Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.SetNativeField(string, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (Test2)
Error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `object' expression to type `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject' (CS1503) (Test2)
```

This is the property is created:

```
#pragma warning disable 0169
    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("window")]
    private object window {
        get {
            this.__mt_window = ((object)(this.GetNativeField("window")));
            return this.__mt_window;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_window = value;
            this.SetNativeField("window", value);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your XIB layout screenshot?

Comment: If I create a new project, the build, it works.  If I open the XIB (in Interface Builder), do not change anything and click save, then build, it fails.  My XIB has nothing in it besides the default window.

Comment: Are you using the most recent software versions?

Comment: That was it.  Can you post this as an answer and I will give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the most recent (and matching) versions of the tools.
For example, [MonoTouch installation page](http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Installation) lists the following requirements for the most recent version:

> - [XCode 3.2.6 and iOS 4.3 SDK](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792)
> - [Mono framework](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) 2.10.3 for Mac OS X - Intel Runtime
> - [MonoDevelop IDE](http://monodevelop.com/Download) 2.4.2 or above